# How can I fix my problem about terminating the program instead of repeat it from the start using while loop? C Language

Tags: c, while-loop

I have new problem about while-loop!

When I input the `l_res` as `y` it means that the condition of while loop is still *TRUE*, instead repeat it from the start, it terminated the program. → [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8wcn.png)

```
int main()
{
    //VARIABLES
    char f_res[4];
    char l_res = 'y';
    int a,b,c,x;

    while(l_res == 'y')
    {
        printf("Enter 3 digit capacitor Code: ");
        scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c);

         x = (a*10)+b;

        printf("What is the unit of the value?(Pico-picofarad, Nano-Nanofarad): ");
        scanf("%s", f_res);

        if(strcmp(f_res, "Pico") == 0)
        {
            if(c == 0)
            {
                 x = x;
            }
            else
            {
                while(c <= 5 && c > 0)
                {
                    c--;
                    x = x*10;
                }
            }
            printf("\nCapacitor value is: %d pF\n\n",x);
        }
        else if(strcmp(f_res, "Nano") == 0)
        {
            float x = ((a*10)+b)*0.001;
            if(c == 0)
            {
                 x = x;
            }
            else
            {
                while(c <= 5 && c > 0)
                {
                    c--;
                    x = x*10;
                }
            }
            printf("\nCapacitor value is: %.3f pF\n\n",x);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nINVALID Input!\n\n");
        }

        printf("Do you want to enter other capacitor Code?( y-Yes, n-No): ");
        scanf(" %c", l_res);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `scanf(" %c", &l_res);`

Comment: Oh right! MB. Thanks that you noticed